# Changing a Programmatically Generated Link to Go Outside Its Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a question regarding links that are created via an onclick event.  I have a chat widget button on this page, https://library.kutztown.edu/ld.php?content_id=41874337, that redirects to a URL that I can set elsewhere.  All I can set is the URL, I do not have access to the anchor tag that the widget creates.

The issue is that I am loading this widget in an iframe, on this page https://library.kutztown.edu/zack_testing and when a user clicks on the Offline button it opens the link inside the iframe.

I have looked into various solutions posted here but all of them seem to involve changing the anchor or adding script to change links on the page.  When I look at the code in the load_chat.php there does not seem to be any anchor link.  I can see the 'offline_url' property of an object named options, but I can't seem to access that object for some reason.

The widget is created using Libguides, it's a library based CMS, and I can't alter their code directly at all.  I'm mostly wondering if anyone has any idea on how I could manipulate their onclick event to open the link in a new tab, rather than inside the iframe.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`window.parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent).location.href do something like

```html
<a href="javascript:window.parent.location.href='https://www.google.com'">Click Me</a>
```

Note that it won't work inside of stackoverflow as their code snippet is in a  [sandboxed iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox), but it should work on yours.

To open in a new tab, you can do the same thing (set the href attribute to javascript: plus the code you want to run), and use [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: I'm not sure that I can use this method since there is no anchor tag in which to place that code.  The button that the user clicks on fires this function, 
`function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault(), clearTimeout(this.chatTimer), this.online || "" === this.config.offline_url ? this.openChat() : window.location.href = this.config.offline_url
}`

rather than using any sort of anchor link.  I should add that I cannot edit that function directly, it is generated by the 'load_chat.php' file that I also cannot edit directly.